# Retrieving the index of deferred jquery ajax request using .when.apply()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-deferred

I have a list of objects, the amount of which unknown that I would like to pass to partial views using ajax posts. The partial view is just a basic table that displays the data how I wish in each partial view. I can do this fine, the problem is, that I would like each partial view to be inside individual div elements because I want to incorporate drag and drop and I think for this I will need to know the div id of the drop? (Correct me if I am wrong here).

This means that I need to firstly dynamically create the divs and assign them their id's using a loop `.each()` and incrementing the id number. I know that I need to use the `.append()` function here and it creates the divs perfectly, naming them correctly.

Now the issue is that I wish to perform an ajax post request to my partial view action for each of the div elements created and I want to change the html to the partial view response. I realise that the ajax calls are asynchronus which is why at first only the last div was updating so I put all the requests in an array and used the `.when.apply().then()` to change the div's html. However I don't know the id of the div to change; I thought that if I could get the index of the current item in the array that I could use that but I am not sure how to get it.

Can someone please look at my code and tell me if I am overcomplicating this or how I can get the index of the div I need to set the html for?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var modelData = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.mappings))][0];
        var divid;
        var ajaxrequests = [];
        $.each(modelData, function (i, item) {
            divid = 'header' + i;
            $('#HeaderData').append('<div id="' + divid + '">Hello</div>');
            ajaxrequests.push($.ajax({
                url: "HeaderFieldMapping",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(item),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html"
            }));
        });
        $.when.apply($, ajaxrequests).then(function (resultdata) {
            divid = 'header' + [index???];
            $('#' + divid).html(resultdata);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Edited previous attempt** Outcome is that it keeps overwritting the last div element

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function rowDropHandler(args) {
        var item = args.data[0];
        alert(item);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var modelData = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.mappings))][0];
        var divid;
        var ajaxrequests = [];
        var intnum = 0;
        $.each(modelData, function (i, item) {
            divid = 'header' + i;
            $('#HeaderData').append('<div id="' + divid + '">Hello</div>');
            ajaxrequests.push($.ajax({
                url: "HeaderFieldMapping",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(item),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(resultdata){
                    $('#' + divid).html(resultdata);
            }
            }));
        });
        $.when.apply($, ajaxrequests).then(function (resultdata) {
            alert('done' + resultdata);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: To do work on the individual AJAX requests, add a `success` handler function within each `$.ajax` call. You can then create the required `table` nested within a `div` for each response.

Comment: I tried that but none of the divs were updating. I used an alert to tell me when they had completed and the alert showed but none of the divs changed. That is why I put the code to change the div html in the `.then()` function. Now the final one will change but none of the others because the `divid` is the id of the final div created.

Comment: Could you update the question to show what you tried in that case. Note that if you use `.html()` then each successive request would overwrite the previous. `append()` would be more appropriate in that case.

Comment: I have updated with previous attempt @RoryMcCrossan.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is indeed because of your use of `html()`. Use `$('#' + divid).append(resultdata);` instead of `.html()`. You can also remove the `$.when` call too

Comment: I added a breakpoint in the browser debugger and watched the last div change when each request was executed. I assume this is because the divid is set to the last created div?

Comment: Using append just creates the partial views inside the final div element

Comment: Going from your question I thought that was your intent... I'm guessing it's not though :)

Comment: No, sorry, I tried to explain the best I could. I want each partial view to be inside it's own div element which is created depending on how many items are in the list (model)

Comment: Your second lot of code is closer to working. you just needed to wrap the Ajax call code in an IIFE to keep the value of the `divid` when the success fires. You do not need the promises in this instance

Comment: @GoneCoding yep, you're right.

Comment: With things like this you almost never need to give appended elements an ID. That's the sort of approach I adopted 17+ years ago when I first started writing Dynamic HTML (DHTML) as we called it at the time. Consider writing `var $div = $('<div>Hello</div>').appendTo('#HeaderData');` inside the `.each()` callback. Now, instead of an ID, you have a reference to appended element itself, so there's no need in the success callback to rediscover it from the DOM.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 If I am now going to devlop a drag and drop and these divs are to be drop targets, do they not need id's for me to discover which element was dropped onto?

Comment: I expect not. As it stands, the distinguishing feature of your proposed IDs is the loop counter `i`, which can be rediscovered using jQuery's `.index()` method. This will be reliable providing none of your divs is later removed, and none added. If you need to positively distinguish the divs from each other, then consider using a className or a `,data()` attribute.

Comment: You are right. I have just got my drag drop to work and I need the table id in the partial view and not the id of the div which holds the partial view. BUT I have learnt a lot here so glad I went the long way around it :) Thank you for everyone's help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first `$.when` based version, you will get a separate entry in the `arguments` pseudo-array for each and every promise.   Each of those entries in turn will be an array of the three standard parameters of a `success` handler.

Hence you can simply iterate over that array and fill in your HTML:

```
$.when.apply($, ajaxrequests).then(function() {
    [].forEach.call(arguments, function(result, index) {
        var divid = 'header' + index;
        var resultdata = result[0];
        $('<div>', {id: divid, html: resultdata}).appendTo('#HeaderData');
    });
});
```

p.s. consider using `Array.prototype.map` to convert your array of elements into an array of promises instead of a `.each / push` loop:

```
var ajaxrequests = modelData.map(function(item, index) { // NB: index unused
    return $.ajax({
        url: "HeaderFieldMapping",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html"
    });
});
```

Comment: So, is this using the index of the array to get the order in which they were added which would make the 'divid' the same? I assume I would still need the `$.each` to loop through my model data to create the divs in the first place? I will have to look up `Array.prototype.map` to see how that would assist me.

Comment: You could defer the `div` creation and drop it inside the `.forEach` call here instead - I'll update accordingly (and yes, the index of the array ends up making the divid's the same)

Comment: Ahhh I see what the Array.map does now. It runs a function for each item in the array. Thanks for that.

Comment: @HollyMarieBatchelor I've added an example for `.map`

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once! It is clean, easy to follow and works a treat (bar an extra bracket) Thank you so much for your help; I have been working on this all day googling it in every way I could think of to no avail. Clearly I wasn't looking for the right thing but then again I had no idea what I was looking for.

Comment: @HollyMarieBatchelor you're welcome - and I've fixed the extra bracket!

Answer (score 1):

Your second lot of code is closer to working. you just needed to wrap the Ajax call code in an IIFE to keep the value of the divid when the success fires. You do not need the promises in this instance:

e.g. something like this:

```
$(function() {  // <<< Shortcut for DOM ready handler
  var modelData = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.mappings))][0];
  var divid;
  var intnum = 0;
  $.each(modelData, function(i, item) {
    divid = 'header' + i;
    $('#HeaderData').append('<div id="' + divid + '">Hello</div>');
    (function(divid) {
      $.ajax({
          url: "HeaderFieldMapping",
          type: "POST",
          data: JSON.stringify(item),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(resultdata) {
            $('#' + divid).html(resultdata);
          }
        )
      }(divid);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: this is unnecessarily complicated - the variable `i` is already bound in the closure so the simplest fix would have been to put the calculation of `divid = 'header' + i` inside the callback and not use an IIFE.

Comment: Brilliant! I had never heard of a IIFE before! (New to web/jquery) The brackets in your code gave me some jip but sorted it out eventually. I can't find the div elements in the source but I will figure out why when I try to build my drop function! Thanks again! (Also thanks for the shortcut for DOM ready!)

Comment: @HollyMarieBatchelor the IIFE is completely unnecessary (albeit it avoids repeating one trivial line of code).  Alternatively defer creating the `header` divs until inside the callback, too.

Comment: @Alnitak: Appreciated. But why put it there to begin with. There are multiple answers to this problem. I just went to for easy to follow one :)

Comment: consider that just putting `var divid = 'header' + i` inside the `success` callback would avoid the IIFE completely making it even easier to follow

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity @GoneCoding it is what I need to wrap my head around it. Going to try and get all answers to work so that I can learn!

Comment: @Alnitak: If you put it in the success the order of display is not guaranteed.

Comment: @GoneCoding yes, you're right.  In reality I wouldn't put it in `success` - I was thinking of my Promise based method where the arguments are in the right order.

Comment: FWIW, I'm allergic to IIFEs in the context of binding loop parameters for async callbacks.  They're almost never necessary.  A `forEach` loop (assuming an array of inputs and not just a count from 0 ..< n) provides a ready made bound index parameter.

Comment: A `foreach` or `$.each()` call would also work, but the idea was to show them how close they were to a solution already in their own code.